# Need help to copy text

Tags: html

I am trying to copy font-family like in the image....

My html code is this....
Please tell me how i can copy this style...
css formating code...

```
padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 0px;
letter-spacing: -2px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 26pt;
font-weight: 200;
color: #303030;
```

I want to copy that font style. you can find here...

Please follow link...

http://www.la-web-solutions.com/security.html
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Oswald font is avaible on Google fonts https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald

If you haven't used webfonts before, there is a fairly thorough description here: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started